# How do i invoke a class method by its name (method name as string)?

Tags: objective-c

In my application,i came across a situtation,wherin i need to invoke a particular class method by using method name (NSString).

For ex:- 
there is class called test1 - having method hello.

```
@interface test1 : NSObject{
```

};
-hello:(id)vals;
@end

Now , i need to invoke/execute method hello() from here.

assume (id)instance  is the instance of class test1.

```
-(void) RunFunction:(id)instance andFunctionName:(NSString*)fname andParamters:(id)params {
```

// need to do something like this - is it possible 
// if yes how do i acheive this.
// sample java code starts.
Method m =  instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(fname,params);
m.invoke(fname,params);
// sample java code ends.
}

could anyone help me in this.

Comment: Do you use that spacing and capitalization scheme to hurt us? Under normal circumstances, I'd go in and fix this, but I'm way too tired. But some helpful bits: It's in fact not a class method that you're trying to invoke (it's an instance method). In the meanwhile, learn any one of the many conventions for spacing and capitalization (don't care which, but for god's sake, be consistent); it may also be a good idea to review Apple's Objective-C guide, if you're having trouble understanding things like the difference between class and instance methods.

Comment: @jonathan sterling - its my mistake saying class method instead of instance method.thank you for pointing my mistakes and giving your valuable suggestions.

Comment: By the way, @Giridhar, I feel like I was a little bit too harsh in my comment before.

Answer (score 4):

You would use `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]`. In this case:

```
[instance performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(fname) withObject:params]
```

Comment: you can't use this if method has more then 2 params.

Comment: His anticipated use case requires only a single object as a parameter. This is the most appropriate solution, IMO.

Comment: For more than one argument you can use NSInvocation. Have a look at http://excitabyte.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/spawning-threads-using-selectors-with-multiple-parameters/